# Dynamically modifying cross reference tool tip text

Tags: ms-word

I have a series of cross-references in my Word documents. I am trying to run code that updates each cross-reference tool tip text to be the paragraph of text at the target location.

The structure of my cross-references is ‘Insert as hyperlink’, ‘Paragraph number (full context)’ and ‘Include above/below’.

I am trying to write code that iterates through each cross-reference in the document and changes the tool tip text as indicated above.

I observe that, in any Word doc that has cross-references, hovering over the cross-reference displays the text ‘Current Document; Ctrl+Click to follow link’. I am trying to ascertain if this text is dynamically modifiable, or if this text is hard-wired into Microsoft's compiled code. I am afraid that such text is not modifiable. ☹

Comment: It's not modifiable. The message is what is shown for a hyperlink and has nothing to do with this being a cross-reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is hyperlinks, not cross-references. The 'Ctrl+Click to follow link' text is only modifiable to the extent that you can change it to 'Click to follow link' by editing the 'Use Ctrl+Click to follow Hyperlink' option. The remainder of the screen tip can be made to show the reference paragraph with code like:

```
Dim HLnk As Hyperlink
For Each HLnk In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
  With HLnk
    If .Address = "" Then .ScreenTip = Split(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(.SubAddress).Range.Paragraphs.First.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
  End With
Next
```

Comment: I am not interested in the ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks objects.
I am referring to the collection ActiveDocument.Range.Fields.
I serialised some of its properties as follows (where SourceText is computed by accessing ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks("_Ref28680085"):
'".Code.Text: REF _Ref28680085 \w \p \h  |.Type:wdFieldRef |FieldKind:wdFieldKindWarm |SourceText:[From document]"
I now need to access the hyperlink Object that Is related to this field and change its tooltip to the SourceText value.
I tried ActiveDocument.Range.Hyperlinks("_Ref28680085") but this does not exist.

Comment: There is no hyperlink object attached to or related to a cross-reference. The \h switch in a cross-reference field merely gives a cross-reference *some* of the characteristics of a hyperlink. If you changed the cross-references concerned to hyperlinks, the code I posted would do as you require - but you might also need to then consider how the hyperlinks should be formatted.